# how can i vary the sizes of the pie charts based on pie chart totals?

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to use d3 to construct an array of pie charts that vary in size based on the total value of the data in the pie chart.

Does anyone know how i could take the html file from the d3 example:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3888852

And modify the pie charts radii to be proportional to the total of the data from the csv file for that pie chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick attempt:

```
...

data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.total = 0;
    d.ages = color.domain().map(function(name) {
      d.total += +d[name]; // add a total of all population for each state
      return {name: name, population: +d[name]};
    });
  });

  // determine the maximum population for all states (ie California)
  var maxPopulation = d3.max(data, function(d){
    return d.total;
  });

  // now for each d.age (where the the arcs come from)
  // stash an arc function based on a scaled size
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    var r = radius * (d.total / maxPopulation);
    var someArc = d3.svg.arc() // make the radius scale according to our max population
      .outerRadius(r)
      .innerRadius(r - (r-10));
    d.ages.forEach(function(a){
      a.arc = someArc; // stash the arc in the d.ages data so we can access later
    })
  });

  ...  
  svg.selectAll(".arc")
    .data(function(d) { return pie(d.ages); })
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "arc")
    .attr("d", function(d){
      return d.data.arc(d);  // use our stashed arc function to create the path arc
    })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.name); })
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qosdZlLuXasjIki54T2l?p=preview).

You might have to change out how I scale the size of the pie.  My linear approach works but some state have such few people compared to CA that their pie charts are view-able.